# what is osx_brew and can i install it in my ubuntu machin?

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I have tried so many tries to correct the issues with ruby version. In between somewhere i have installed osx_brew in my machine. Actually i don't know why i have install this. After a short googling i can found that the osx_brew only needed for mac os. I don't know that is correct or not. Any way when i try to install `rvm requirements` i got the error like

```
Installing requirements for osx_brew, might require sudo password.
Already up-to-date.
Installing required packages: autoconf, automake, libtool, pkg-config, apple-gcc42, libyaml, readline, libxml2, libxslt, libksba, openssl, sqlite...
Error running 'requirements_brew_libs_install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config apple-gcc42 libyaml readline libxml2 libxslt libksba openssl sqlite',
please read /home/anoop/.rvm/log/package_install_autoconf_automake_libtool_pkg-config_apple-gcc42_libyaml_readline_libxml2_libxslt_libksba_openssl_sqlite.log
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.
Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation
```

i don't know whether this problem arises due to `homebrew` or not.

Also when i try the command `rvm autolibs status`

it shows me like

```
---
value: osx_brew
number: 4
runner: osx_brew
description: Allow RVM to use package manager if found, install missing dependencies, install package manager (only OS X).
```

It says like only for osx_homebrew. Do i need to install when i working in rvm ruby if yes can you tell me the purpose of that. If i don't need this how can i remove this in my ubuntu system?

Comment: ...What are you trying to accomplish? Homebrew is a tool to install software on an OS X machine that's **written** in Ruby. It shouldn't be required to develop software in Ruby. It doesn't make sense at all to install it in Ubuntu.

Comment: Not sure why rvm thinks you should use an os x only option. You could try `rvm autolibs reset` to reset it.